# Exchange on Windows 10 2013/2016 Outlook 2013/2016 Error: "MAPI 1.0 [4C2]

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-outlook-2016

```
The time limit for logging on was reached while waiting for system resources. Try Again.
MAPI 1.0 [000004C2]
```

Is the error I get when I try and open Outlook.

The system will lock up if I try and create a new profile.

What is causing this? I have a business plague by these outlook issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From research I determined our issue was using SalesForce. Uninstalling Salesforce fixed the issue for us.

Might not be related to other people having this issue, unless you run plugins but it might be a possible solution for some.

**Either-way, I'm all about disabling ALL automatic Microsoft updates for Office AND Windows. This year alone I've seen more damage done from automatic uptates and have found disabling them is BEST.**

Comment: disabling updates is never a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I can verify that a customer of mine who had both:

1. Salesforce for Outlook

and

2. Outlook 2016 (two separate users with the same setup)

Ran into the SAME exact issue.
No other fixes were successful other than simply **uninstalling the Salesforce for Outlook** plugin at this time.

*Also, you need to kill the running process for Salesforce for Outlook, as the uninstaller has issues accessing it.*

**I do not believe Salesforce and Outlook 2016 work well together at this time.**

Comment: This is correct. Witnessed this as a fix as well. I believe this also falls back to Outlook 2013 as well.

Comment: Same issue here too, salesforce plugin

Answer (score 1):

I have found this on microsoft site that it was saying that it could be a configured compatibility issue or else the check the date and time. If you can't able to clear this issue check out this link http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/cannot-set-up-micsosoft-outlook-2013-on-new-pc/8429012f-96f1-4536-98f8-a1f9cd92787a?db=5&auth=1

Answer (score 1):

Signed up so I could say this...

At my business, we started getting plagued with this error on all of our computers, one by one. Started with one person, now 75 out of 135 are impacted and more every hour/day.

Our configuration:

Windows 10 Professional

Office 365 Exchange

Office 2016 Business Premium (from O365)

From what we can tell at this point, this only impacts our Windows 10/Office 2016 machines, not our Windows 7/Office 2013 machines.

We called Microsoft to open a case multiple times, but they just keep telling us to uninstall, delete the local user profile altogether (deleting the mail profile DOES NOT work), and then reinstall and have the user log back in and set back up their account/profile in Outlook. This didn't work either for more than 48 hours, so now they gave us some sort of FixIt tool to run after the uninstall, before reinstalling Office. No word yet on the longevity of this fix.

I suspect there's something funky with a Windows 10 update or an Office update that's hosing everything up that they just haven't noticed yet.

Comment: Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Answer (score 1):

If the other solutions such as outlook.exe /safe, Creating a new Outlook Profile and Renaming the Profile key in the registry don't work, try the following.

Check the versions of MAPI32.DLL in c:\windows\system32 and c:\windows\sysWow64 and make sure they are the correct ones for the Outlook version you are trying to run.  I had a user that had this issue after installing Office 365 Pro Plus (2016) on a system that had Office 2010 installed and the install never updated the files.  After copying the newer files from a system with a working Outlook 2016 install, this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using process explorer to find handles for "outlook", and kill all process that get hold of it, such as powerpoint, bluejeans, excel, and etc. Then delete or remove the folder "C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook". After this step, you can run "outlook /safe" and create a new profile, "the time limit for logging on was reached" error will disappear.